# Devise: Sign user in if duplicate sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise

I would like to sign a user in if he attempts to sign up a second time ie. email and password in params is exactly the same.

I added this line to my RegistrationsController (if a duplicate email is detected)

```
resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
```

however I can get it to successfully authenticate even though the correct email and password is provided in the params. am I missing something?

I'm on Rails 3.2 and Devise 2.2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @user = User.find_by_email(email)
  if @user and @user.confirmed? and @user.valid_password?(password)
    sign_in @user, :bypass => true                
  end
```

Comment: thanks! this work. any idea why warden.authenticate! doesn't?

Comment: no idea, I struggled a lot with warden myself before switching to this solution